# Some question about the spectral function of Laplace operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, sp.spectral-theory, hyperbolic-pde

I am studying the paper of *Seeley, R.*, [**A sharp asymptotic remainder estimate for the eigenvalues of the Laplacian in a domain of (R^3)**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(78)90013-0), Adv. Math. 29, 244-269 (1978). [ZBL0382.35043](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0382.35043). There are some question about the spectral function $e(x,y,\lambda)$ confused me very much, I hope someone can help me.

Consider the Laplace operator $\Delta=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\partial_{x_{j}}^{2}$  in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and let $E_{\lambda}$ be the spectral resolution of  $\Delta$. I know that $E_{\lambda}$ is a projector from $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ to $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$. By using of the Schwarz kernel Theorem, we can obtain a Schwarz kernel $e(x,y,\lambda)$ of $E_{\lambda}$, and $e(x,y,\lambda)\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any $\lambda>0$. It seems by the regularity estimates of Laplace operator, we can conclude that $e(x,y,\lambda)\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$ for any fixed $\lambda>0$. In many papers (e.g. [1]), the authors used notation
$$ u(x,y,t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos{\lambda t}~d_{\lambda}e(x,y,\lambda^{2}) $$
to the wave kernel of $\Delta$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which satisfies
$$\left\{
  \begin{array}{ll}
  u_{tt}-\Delta u=0  , &  \\
  u|_{t=0}=\delta(x-y),\qquad u|_{t=0}=0 & 
  \end{array}
\right.$$

For $n=3$, Seeley obtained that
$$u(x,y,t)=(2\pi)^{-3}4\pi\int \cos(t\tau) \tau^{2} d\tau=\frac{1}{6\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t\tau)d\tau^{3} $$
Then, he claimed that the spectral function $e(x,y,\lambda)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is
$$ e(x,x,\tau^2)=\frac{1}{6\pi^{2}}\tau^{3} $$ by compare the two equations above.

My questions are as follows:

1. I feel very confused about how can we write the notation $d_{\lambda}e(x,y,\lambda)$? Is $e(x,y,\lambda)$ a function of bounded variation with respect to variable $\lambda$ for fixed $x,y$ that make $d_{\lambda}e(x,y,\lambda)$ as a measure? What's the properties of $e(x,y,\lambda)$ ?
2. How can we recover the spectral function $e(x,x,\tau^2)=\frac{1}{6\pi^{2}}\tau^{3}$ by only compare
   $$u(x,y,t)=(2\pi)^{-3}4\pi\int \cos(t\tau) \tau^{2} d\tau=\frac{1}{6\pi^{2}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(t\tau)d\tau^{3} $$
   with
   $$ u(x,y,t)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos{\lambda t}~d_{\lambda}e(x,y,\lambda^{2})? $$  The first integral does not converge and $u(x,y,t)$ is only a distribution.

I find many books but get nothing, can someone give some reference about the **fundamental theory** of spectral function and wave kernel for elliptic operators?  Thank you very much!

**Reference**
[1]
*Ivrii, Victor*, [**100 years of Weyl’s law**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s13373-016-0089-y), Bull. Math. Sci. 6, No. 3, 379-452 (2016). [ZBL1358.35075](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1358.35075).

Comment: Nice question! +1.

Comment: I have no idea how far one can extend it, but for the Laplace operator this looks like Fourier inversion formula in disguise: we have $f(-\Delta)u(x)=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}\int_{\mathbb R^n}f(|\xi|^2)u(y)e^{-i\xi(x-y)}dyd\xi$; write the integral over $\xi$ in "polar" coordinates $\xi = r \zeta$ with $|\zeta| = 1$, and substitute $\lambda = r^2$, to get an expression of the form $f(-\Delta) u(x) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \int_0^\infty e_\lambda(x,y) f(\lambda) u(y) d\lambda dy$, and hence the expression for $e_\lambda$ in terms of a spherical integral over $\zeta$.

Answer (score 3):

This integral is understood as a Fourier transform of a temperate distribution and it is itself a temperate distribution.

---

From comments below:

1: How to understand $\int f(\tau) d\tau e(x,x,\tau)$: Since for Laplacian and elliptic operators in general $e(x,x,\tau)$ is a smooth function of $x, y$ with a value in the space of temperate distributions, there is no reason to worry how to understand this integral. Furthermore, it is not a measure, but more singular distribution in higher dimensions.

2: We do not recover $e(x,x,\tau)$ from $u(x,x,t)$ for all $t$ as in most cases it is impossible to construct an approximation for all $t$, but only for $t$ in small vicinity of $0$. Then we use Tauberian theorem of Hormander. I suggest to start from more elementary books;  M. Shubin, Pseudodifferential operators and spectral theory would be the best.